# I can't see some image on Matisse from gallery in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to send an image from Gallery using Matisse library in my android application. But this library is not showing me all images that I have in gallery. Here is my code:

```
private fun showMatisse() {
       Log.i("ChatMatisse", "showMatisse()")
      Matisse
          .from(this@OnlineChatFragment)
          .choose(MimeType.ofAll())
          .countable(true)
          .maxSelectable(1)
          .imageEngine(Glide4Engine())
          .forResult(CHOOSE_IMAGE_RESULT_CODE)
  }
```

Comment: not sure what we can do for you here if it's an issue with that library, you'll have to find another or an alternative way of doing it

Comment: Do you have any alternative library for that?

Comment: nope and asking for libraries here is considered off-topic

Comment: If you have one  why not to tell ?

Comment: like i said, i don't have one, i avoid 3rd party libraries as far as possible for this exact reason, if they stop working then you have a problem

Comment: The library developer has not released an update to the library since 2019. It is outdated.